# WebApi Owin token returning 401 way too soon

Tags: asp.net-web-api, token, owin

using mostly default WebAPI 2.2 Owin authentication, and soon after the token is issued we get 401 unauthorized.  Code is configured to expire in 90 days... any ideas why?  Yes we want to also use refresh tokens but haven't got a chance to implement...

```
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/authenticate"),
            Provider = new MyTokenProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(90),
            //AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use With This Way

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
    //Rest of code is here;
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you cracker but didn't help... still get 401 after a short while... could it be the ASP.net cookies expiring or something?  wouldn't think so, but not sure what else to do...

Comment: Yes That might be because of the Cookies refer this and try to set the cookie. => http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx